# REST service consume with PHP 7

Tags: php, rest

As I am new to this PHP world I require some help to consume rest request with php. What I have already achieved is to submit json thoug jquery($("#form").serialize) and read the same in php along with returning json value in the response of the server call.

But I am bit stuck when I have to read rest url parameter with php. For example in case of select by Id my client calls me with url mentioned below. Now I would like to retrieve 1 and fetch from the url. With Spring pathvariable it's easy but how I can parse this url in php.

**`/dummy/customer/1/fetch`**

Note - As of now I am not using any framework only raw php.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of different ways to do this. I'll show 2 ways.

## Basic string functions

We can simply split the string on `/` and grab the 4th part.

```
$output = explode($input, '/')[3];
```

## Regular expressions

This example of a regular expression doesn't just grab the `1`, it also ensures that all the other parts in the url are what you expect. Regular expressions are harder but more versatile.

```
$matches = null;
$success = preg_match('#^/dummy/customer/([0-9]+)/fetch$#', $input, $matches);
if (!$success) {
  throw new Exception('Unexpected format');
} 
$output = $matches[1];
```

Comment: Not part of this post but I am planning to use laravel for my development. So, can you tell me a good tutorial to do the same.

Comment: Code that you write in plain PHP also runs in frameworks.